# How do I add and remove classes using event listeners in Lit-HTML?

Tags: javascript, lit-html

I would like to add and remove `'over'` from my class on an element created using a lit-html template triggered by 'dragEnter' and 'dragLeave':

```
#app {
  background-color: #72a2bc;
  border: 8px dashed transparent;
  transition: background-color 0.2s, border-color 0.2s;
}

#app.over {
  background-color: #a2cee0;
  border-color: #72a2bc;
}
```

```
const filesTemplate = () =>
html`
  <button id="app"     
    @dragover=${??}
    @dragleave=${??}     
  >
    Click Me
  </button>
`;
```

In my old system I called these methods in a separate module via an event emitter, but I am hoping I can make it all defined in the template using lit-html.

```
 dragEnter(e) {
    this.view.element.className += ' over';
  }

  dragLeave(e) {
    this.view.element.className = element.className.replace(' over', '');
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends what your custom element looks like. With your template you could just put `@dragover=${this.dragEnter}`. However, if you want this to apply to your entire custom element and not just the button you can do something like this:

```
connectedCallback() {
super.connectedCallback();

this.addEventListener('dragover', this.dragEnter);

}
```

If you do not have custom element and just use lit-html by itself you have to put your event handlers `dragEnter(e)`and `dragLeave(e)` into the template like so: `@dragover=${this.dragEnter}`

You need to add the class with `classList.add` in dragEnter and remove it in dragLeave. In the future you maybe can use `classMap` directive in lit-html, however there is nothing wrong with just using `classList`. I would stick with just using classList. In a very distant future css might also have a selector for it: [Is there a CSS ":drop-hover" pseudo-class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42853699/is-there-a-css-drop-hover-pseudo-class)

Comment: I don't have any custom elements, I am using lit-html by itself, not with lit-element or some equivalent. I am not sure how your code relates to the CSS, are you saying I have to use a callback to `this.dragEnter`, if so, what would be in that method, how will it refer to the <button>? Cheers!

Comment: Updated the answer based on your comment.

Comment: Thanks for the update, but it is only a partial answer, you did not address the CSS or what the dragEnter() method might contain. I am new to lit-html and the docs are woefully inadequate right now (it is pre-release still). What is best practice? Should my methods mutate the DOM as before? Should I feed in new variables into the template/re-write it with new bindings for class? Run the render() function again after each callback? If you could provide a full solution in code would be great :) Thanks for your time, it is much appreciated!

Comment: Added some more clarification

Comment: Cheers! classMap was what I was looking for, seems made for the job :) Nothing in the docs, but the comments in the source code explain https://github.com/Polymer/lit-html/blob/master/src/directives/class-map.ts

Comment: Yes, they are a bit behind on documentation at the moment sadly.

Answer (score 2):

I think that, in order to solve the problem in a "lit-html style", the solution has to be something like this:

```
import { html, render} from 'lit-html';
import { classMap } from 'lit-html/directives/class-map.js';

const myBtnClasses = {
  over: false
};
function dragEnter(e) {
  myBtnClasses.over = true;
  renderFiles();
}
function dragLeave(e) {
  myBtnClasses.over = false;
  renderFiles();
}

const filesTemplate = (classes) =>
html`
  <button id="app" class="${classMap(myBtnClasses)}"
    @dragover=${dragEnter} @dragleave=${dragLeave}     
  >
    Click Me
  </button>
`;
function renderFiles() {
  render(filesTemplate(myBtnClasses), YOUR_CONTAINER);
}
```

When using `lit-html` you have to express your UI as a function of your "state" and "rerender" each time your state changes, so the best solution in this little example is to consider your classes as part of your state.

Answer (score 0):

Anyway better than

```
this.view.element.className += ' over';
```

is

```
this.view.element.classList.add('over');
```

And instead

```
this.view.element.className = element.className.replace(' over', '');
```

use

```
this.view.element.classList.remove('over');
```

This is better because of allowing to avoid many bugs like adding the same class many times.

I do not know lit-html but try

```
let sayHello = (name, myClass) => html`<h1 class="${myClass}">Hello ${name}</h1>`;
```

> https://lit-html.polymer-project.org/

Comment: Thanks for the great tip regarding `classList`,  I copied from old code and ender up with cruft, well spotted! I am really looking for the syntax to set the event listeners to make these changes to the class within the lit-html template. Your example code would work in part, but misses the vital syntax to integrate with the event listening :(